# Woocommerce rest API PUT through a react app plugin does not render updated data on WordPress element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, woocommerce-rest-api, wordpress-plugin-creation

I created a React app that renders on a WordPress product page as a shortcode. Within the react app I'm making a few API calls, getting data from an external API, and then using that new data to update the WooCommerce rest API product attributes. The update works, the issue I'm having is with a WooCommerce element on my product page, what I have is an add-to-cart that renders the product variations in two select boxes. When my plugin finishes its calls the selects from the variations do not update to the new data I just sent, this only changes once I reload the page. Is there a way of having the add-to-cart fetch the data so that they can update without having to reload the page?

I already tried updating the Dom directly with the response data, it shows the information but is rewritten once I select something in the boxes. this is an example of my most recent attempt.

```
 // // Step 1: Identify the container element
  const attributeContainer = document.getElementsByClassName(
    "variations_form cart"
  );

  // // Step 2: Make an AJAX request
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
      const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      // Step 3: Extract the new attribute options from the response
      const newAttributes = response.attributes[1].options;
      // Step 4: Update the container with the new attribute options
      attributeContainer.innerHTML = ""; // Clear existing options

      // Add new options dynamically
      newAttributes.forEach((attribute) => {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = attribute;
        option.textContent = attribute;
        attributeContainer.appendChild(option);
      });
      // Step 5: Trigger reinitialization and restore selected value
      attributeContainer.dispatchEvent(new Event("click")); // Simulate click event
      attributeContainer.value = selectedValue; // Restore selected value
    }
  };
  xhr.open(
    "GET",
    `${process.env.API_URL}/wp-json/wc/v3/products/${prodId}`,
    true
  );

  // Step 2a: Add Authorization header for basic authentication
  const username = process.env.CONSUMER_KEY;
  const password = process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET;
  const credentials = btoa(username + ":" + password);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
  xhr.send();
```

I tried changing the priority of loading the elements, having my plugin render first so that the information had already been updated before the selects fetch the data, but that didn't seem to work (I'm not sure I did this right).